# QML grid specify position manually

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Can I set the column and row of QML Grid children elements manually? In this case, I'd like the Button to be in row 11 column 1.

```
 Grid {
        rows: 11
        columns: 4

        Button {
            height: 128
            width: 128
            text: qsTr("Sahtel lahti")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain, what you try to achive? Maybe you're looking for the GridLayout? Otherwise you might populate all columns with invisible dummy Items to which you parent, or with which you replace your Button.

Comment: GridLayout seems to have the options I need. Can you form an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But luckily @Lasall could :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you can use [GridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html) and `Layout.row` and `Layout.column`.

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13

GridLayout {
    columns: 3

    Text { text: "4"; Layout.row: 1; Layout.column: 0}
    Text { text: "3"; Layout.row: 0; Layout.column: 2}
    Text { text: "2"; Layout.row: 0; Layout.column: 1}
    Text { text: "1"; Layout.row: 0; Layout.column: 0}
}
```

Comment: How about `Grid` ?